# PHP prepared statements with LIKE

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm using:

```
   $ordem = "%".$_GET['ordem']."%"; 
    $arr = [];

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT texto,data_hora FROM logs WHERE texto LIKE ?");  
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$ordem);
    $stmt->execute();
```

The `$ordem` variable is receiving a value that contains in DB, but is not found...

What's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You either need to write this: `"'%".$_GET['ordem']."%'"` or that `....WHERE texto LIKE '?'` because you try to search for a string apparently and therefore you have to use `'`.

Comment: If i write ````'%".$_GET['ordem']."%'```` i get an error 500

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT texto, data_hora FROM logs WHERE texto LIKE '%?%'");  
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_GET['ordem']);
```

or try below which is similar to what you did

```
$param = "%{$_GET['ordem']}%";
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT texto, data_hora FROM logs WHERE texto LIKE ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $param);
```

Comment: Have you verified that `$_GET['ordem']` contains what you expect?